# vue.js Route is removing a hash from a parameter value (Mode: History)

Tags: vue.js

My VUE route is removing a hash '#' from the route parameter.

Value that is passed in: `/project/test%20#report`
Parameter value received in Component: `'test '`

all characters after the # are removed.
*other values/characters are being passed.

**Is there a way to get a # passed to the component while the router mode is set to history?**

Vue.js route:

Mode has been set to 'history'

```
{
  path: '/project/:projectId/',
  name: 'project',
  beforeEnter: requireAuth,
  component: Project,
  props: true
},
```

Component prop declaration:

```
props: ['projectId'],
```

Answer (score 0):

hash is technically NOT part of the path.

you can get the current's url's hash in any component using `this.$route.hash`.

Comment: hey Jacob, thanks for the information but this isn't quite solving the issue. 
When the router originally sends the user to this component, the # and following text is available. If a user was to refresh the page, the # and value are not available in the $route.hash. I could just JavaScript to grab and parse the full path but that feels wrong.

For now, we've decided to disallow # in the projectId field. Not a great solution - but a solution that will stop the error.